# Model averaging in mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-averaging

I am reading this blog post regarding using model averaging for mixed models and the last para says

"https://sites.google.com/site/rforfishandwildlifegrads/home/mumin_usage_examples"

`One word of warning, do not estimate model averaged parameters for mixed models! You can, however, model average the predictions of GLMM`.

Could anyone explain why this cannot be done and in case I want to model average the parameters from multiple mixed models, how to go about it?

Comment: The only thing I can guess is that they're warning against model-averaging mixed models *that are fitted via restricted maximum likelihood* (REML).  If you use maximum likelihood instead (e.g. `REML=FALSE` in lme4 or method="ML" in nlme) it should be fine.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. This is what I have done. My models were fitted using REML = FALSE and then I did model averaging on them